# How to keep the focus on the current data table on a lengthy data page

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am working on an application where i have some data tables listed one by one on a lengthy page (I know this it's a bad user experience, but this is my requirement).

There is an option to create a customer for one of a data table.

**Issue:** When i click the add button, the page scrolls to the top, which confuses the user by not letting which data table he made the changes.

I know this will do,

```
$('html, body').scrollTop( $(document).height() );
```

Any workaround other than this, to stay back on the same location where the data-table resides? or is the browser's default behavior? This is happening in all the browsers.

**Note:** I am not refreshing the page.

Comment: If you are not refreshing the page, then why the page scrolls to the top? Is your button not an actual button, but a link with `href='#'` or something?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: No, i am not refreshing the page. It is an anchor tag with href='#'.

Comment: It seems that `<a href="#!">Link</a>` won't scroll. Try that.

Comment: Let me try this and update you...

Comment: This is working fine, Thanks @SergioTulentsev